# Insert new Blazor View or Component with JSRuntime (jQuery.append)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor

This seems so simple in theory, but I can't find a way to make it work:

in _Layout.cshtml

```
window.insertComponent = function (selector, component) {
    $(selector).append(component);
}
```

In my main component:

```
private object Model {get;set;}
private string elementId {get;set;}
//...
private async void OnChange(EventArgs e)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("insertComponent", new[] { "#" + elementId, new SomeChildComponentOrView() { Model = this.Model }});
}
```

What, if anything, can I do to make this work? Obviously, `new SomeChildComponentOrView()` won't compile. Where do I go from here?

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you may check your Setup.cs file, it should be configured to add a service and use it.

```
app.UseStaticFile()
```

causing if you don't use it, it will be no function on JS or JQ.